# How do I calculate the size of folders which contains some unreadable contents?

Tags: file-size

The `/var/lib` contains some unreadable contents, one of which is the `mysql` folder. I wanted to see the size of the `/var/lib` folder and the `mysql` folder in particular. Right-clicking on it and clicking on the "Properties" option gives me this:

[image: The Properties dialog box]

In case you need the specs:

- Ubuntu 12.10
- Nautilus 3.4.2

**EDIT:**

```
`du -sh /var/lib` gives me this:
du: cannot read directory `/var/lib/sudo': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory `/var/lib/tor': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory `/var/lib/udisks2': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory `/var/lib/php5': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory `/var/lib/openfire': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory `/var/lib/gdm': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory `/var/lib/lightdm': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory `/var/lib/polkit-1': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory `/var/lib/mysql': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory `/var/lib/libvirt/qemu': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory `/var/lib/libvirt/sanlock': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory `/var/lib/libvirt/images': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory `/var/lib/libvirt/boot': Permission denied
266M    /var/lib
```

and `sudo du -sh /var/lib` gives this:

```
309M    /var/lib
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**sudo du -sh lib/** should do the job. It is showing the size greater than it shows in "Properties" window. root login is required as only root may be having access to some files. **Hence the permission denied and unreadable content errors**.

Comment: Man page of `du` says its an estimate size, is it possible to get an exact size?

Comment: It seems the estimate is the best possible bet, but at least the approx. size is known. Thanks, @Jay!

Answer (score 0):

This is normal behavior. Some of the sub-directories in /var/lib are owned by the services that store files there and cannot be read by other users.

You can view the contents and get sizes of folders/files from the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo du -b /var/lib/
```

gives you an integer in bytes. That's about as exact as you can get! Make sure you leave the trailing / because **sudo du -b /var/lib** will return the size of every file in there.

Comment: Please read the man page of `du`.

Comment: The absolute file space, since one of the reasons I want this is, is to know the size of mysql database.

Comment: Another thing you can do is use **mysqldump** and just look at the size of the file it dumps